# How does the Smite effect work on Sky Splitter?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have bought a [Sky Splitter](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/sky-splitter) from the AH and the weapon description says:

`10-20% chance to Smite enemies when you hit them.`

[image: Cropped screenshot of Sky Splitter page from the Game Guide]

How does this work exactly?

How much and what kind of damage does Smite deal?

Can it be resisted, and if yes, does it scale with monster level or difficulty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, I am not sure if it stacks with a Barbian that is currently using Frenzy and a Smite rune.

**Now to what it does:**

The Smite effect works like the ability/rune.

Frenzy - Smite Rune: 20% chance to call down a bolt of lightning from above, stunning your target for 1.5 seconds.

I remember back in patch 1.04 or 1.05, my Sky Splinter was stunning, and doing damage when the smite occured (roughly 2k extra damage) on the enemies.

[Source](http://www.diablo3skills.net/2012/01/barbarian-smite.html)

Comment: I'm not sure I am seeing a stunning effect on hit. But other than that, looks similar to the Smite rune.

Comment: They may have removed the stun effect, or I was actually using smite when it did stun them.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, Smite does not actually deal any damage.

Smite is simply a stun, so it's % chance to stun an enemy.